# How do I install the UplinkOS mod on Uplink? I only have the .iso file

Tags: technical-issues, pc, uplink

The title says all. I've already installed the ISO, so I have the the files. The UplinkOS mod can be found [here.](http://www.moddb.com/mods/uplink-os)

Comment: The body section isn't for show. Notice that the mod says its for Steam?

Comment: There is also a download for the GOG version at that moddb link, which might work with the CD version from Humble as well. But anway "title says it all" is not enough, Campbell Sloan, please provide more information on what version of uplink you want to mod. I suggest as well to read the moddb page more thoroughly, the downloads all provide an installation guide in the description.

Comment: I'm not sure about what update mine is. I have a screencap of the folder [here,](http://i.imgur.com/wXSK0eW.png) but whenever I try to launch UplinkOS.exe it just says sdl.dll and sdl_mixer.dll are missing, and then closes. @Crovaxon

Comment: Okay. So where'd you get the game from? That seems like relevant information.

Comment: Does Uplink work without the mod?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your mention of an ISO file I can only assume it is a physical release or something like that. 
According to [the UplinkOS moddb page](http://www.moddb.com/mods/uplink-os) the GOG version of this mod might also work with the Humble and **CD** release. So I advise to download and follow the installation instructions in the description of the download for the **GOG version**: [here](http://www.moddb.com/mods/uplink-os/downloads/uplinkos-v104-gold-for-gog).

Here is the install description for at this answer's time current version: UplinkOS GOG version 104 gold:

> Installation
>
> Inside the archive you'll find the UplinkOS executable, its resource files and the ReadMe.
>   In case you're like me and you don't read ReadMes, here's the installation instructions:
>
> First you'll need the GOG Version of the game. (this version may work on the Humble Bundle version too; haven't tested it)
>
> After downloading the Mod, unzip it into a place of your choice.
>
> Go to Uplink's installation folder. In GOG's case, the default is: C:\GOG Games\Uplink
>
> Copy the contents of the Mod's zip file into this folder.
>
> Go to the "users" folder. Back-up & move/delete all the files here.
>
> Now just run UplinkOS.exe and your ready to start hacking!

For newer/other versions please follow the included Readme or the description on the moddb download page.

Comment: I've gotten all the files into my Uplink folder, however it's saying I am missing sdl.dll and sdl_mixer.dll.

Comment: Hmm is uplink running without any mods?

Comment: Only mod I'm trying to run is UplinkOS. When I try to launch the game normally, it works fine.

Comment: Then I fear my answer is not helpful in this case... You could try and take your error messages to the moddb forum of this mod. Another thing that might help would be see if your version of uplink itself is the most recent, try applying the latest patch from https://www.introversion.co.uk/uplink/otherfiles.html and see if uplink still runs fine. Afterwards reapply the mod and see if it works now.